# AWS boto3 route53 create_health_check fails after the health check is deleted manually

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-route53

I created a Route 53 health check using boto3 sdk. After creating the health check I deleted them manually from the AWS console. But now it throws the below error when I try to create the health check using the same caller reference:

`ClientError: An error occurred (HealthCheckAlreadyExists) when calling the CreateHealthCheck operation: A different health check has already been created with the specified caller reference.`

How can I tell Route 53 that the health check doesnt exist anymore?

Answer (score 0):

Use a different Caller Reference.  The purpose of this opaque value is to prevent accidentally sending the same request more than once (making retries safe when you don't know whether a request was processed, such as might be the case with a network timeout error).

The fact that you deleted the previous check isn't relevant. You not only need a unique string for each *check*, you need a unique string for each *request*.

> **CallerReference**
>
> A unique string that identifies the request and that allows failed `CreateHealthCheck` requests to be retried without the risk of executing the operation twice. You must use a unique `CallerReference` string every time you create a health check.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/APIReference/API_CreateHealthCheck.html#API_CreateHealthCheck_RequestSyntax

Eventually (after some period of hours or days) you can *probably* reuse caller references, but the service is behaving as designed by blocking your request.

Comment: I want to use the same caller reference so that even if the code is executed more than once it wont create multiple health checks.

Comment: Right.  But you've already done it once.  The fact that you deleted it later doesn't matter.  Route 53 has no way of knowing you're not a delayed message that got stuck in a buggy queue somewhere and is just now arriving... again... and if it allowed the message to process, it would be creating a health check that you've already created *and* already asked it to delete.

Comment: I wish route 53 tracked the caller reference details along with route 53 recordset. So that it can understand when the record was deleted manually. Anyways I guess I will have to come up with some workaround to deal with this situation.

Comment: Why are you constantly deleting health checks?  One solution is to use a guid and have a lambda function come in and delete health checks that aren't referenced in any of your zones.